# EKF not providing good position estimation

Tags: odometry, imu, robot-localization, ekf, position

I am working on a robotics project and I am using the package robot_localization in ROS2. I am trying to fuse the wheel odometry and IMU data, but I am struggling a lot to make it work. I've read a lot of discussion through the ROS2 forums, but none of them seems to help me.

Pictures and EKF file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MyVo2CMQ5vFdLfaVPn-7pZZkoxOstdZK?usp=sharing

Basically, I am using the EKF to fuse the data of wheel odometry and the BNO055 IMU from Bosch, but I faced some situations that are quite strange for me. The first picture shows the map I am using. When navigation starts (in the room with the blue point)), autonomously or manually operated, there is some points that it's possible to see that the LIDAR data don't match with the map, like in the second picture that it's the red region in the map. But when we go to the end of the hallway and are back in the same region, it seems that the LIDAR data matches with the corners, like in the third picture. But, when we're entering back the room it's possible to see that the LIDAR data don't match again (the door is closed for the robot, like in the fourth picture).

Does anyone faced similar situation? I don't know if the EKF is really my problem here, but it's the only reason I could thought. I know the EKF is a excellent filter, and in some robotics cases, it's the only position estimation available, and works great.

There is one more situation that it's strange. When the robot is in the middle of these big hallways,I noticed that the LIDAR data in the end of the hallways are detecting the wall ahead than the map's wall, like in the orange line drawn in the first picture. Shouldn't the AMCL be able to reposition the robot in the right place from the LIDAR data?

Comment: Please include your full EKF config (remove any comments) and a sample message from each sensor input, and please include them directly in the question. Thanks.